# How to get id from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url and just want to get the id:

```
https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/223ac74c-0a2f-4f36-b78b-a8ad8a6e3009
```

Guess I could just look for the '/' at the end and split up the string into substring. What would be a more elegant/better way to just get the id: 223ac74c-0a2f-4f36-b78b-a8ad8a6e3009?

Comment: Match `/\d+$/`? `split` is fine too

Comment: location.pathname.split('/').pop() is one approach (assuming no hash or query params in url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.substring` or regex

```js
let url = 'https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/112233444';
let id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log(id);

// Or using regex
id = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];
console.log(id);

// If your id is some hash or uuid then
url  = 'https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/223ac74c-0a2f-4f36-b78b-a8ad8a6e3009';
console.log(url.match(/video\/(.*)$/)[1]);
```

Comment: awesome dude thanks

Comment: I updated answer, don't forget to add `$` at the end of regex otherwise it will match any number inside url

Comment: What if the id looks like this:223ac74c-0a2f-4f36-b78b-a8ad8a6e3009

Comment: @bierhier Updated answer. Added similar scenario

Comment: many thanks, good on ya